# Inherit specific tests from the test class pytest

Tags: pytest

Is there any way to import specific tests from the pytest class.
For example:

test_collection.py

```
class TestCollection:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [1, 2])
    def test_1(self, a):
        # some test
        assert a == 1

    def test_2(self):
        # some test
```

test_all_functions.py

```
class TestEvrything:
    TestCollection.test_2
    
    def test_3(self):
       # some test
    
    Test_collection.test_1
```

So I want to import and launch specific tests from test_collection file with all the marks.

Is there a way to do it?

P.S. I know about nesting the class, but in this case I cannot control the order of the tests and will need to constantly add tests to skip if I add them to the test collection

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [pytest-dependency](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)? Not sure why the specific order is needed, but maybe this'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ok it took me a while to figure out what are you asking, your post-scriptum was pretty deceptive.
Anyway...I don't think that is really possible to achieve what you want. Tell me if I'm wrong, or if you have found a solution.
If I understood correctly, you want a way to change someway the second file called *test_all_functions.py*, to avoid specifying in the first *test_collection.py* file which method need to be ignored from **pytest *test_all_functions.py*** command.
I've tried a few solutions, but I came to the conclusion that it is not possible to reach your goal without adding any decorator (skip or filterwarnings) to methods of your *TestCollection* class. It can only be imported in its entirety.
In conclusion, I'm quite sure it is impossible to specify which test should be executed by adding certain instructions/tricks inside the main *test_all_functions.py* file.
Moreover, I've tried various options to add to the pytest command, without success.

Just for clarification purposes, here's a working example of what we are talking about, that it is probably similar, in the form, to the one you have.

```
# test_collection.py
import pytest

def my_add(a, b):
    return a + b
def my_sub(a, b):
    return a - b
def my_mul(a, b):
    return a * b

class TestCollection:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b, expected', [
        (1, 2, 3),
        (0, 0, 0),
        (-1, 1, 0),
        (2, -4, -2)
    ])    
    def test_add_numbers(self, a, b, expected):
        assert my_add(a, b) == expected

    def test_add_large_numbers(self):
        assert my_add(1000000, 2000000) == 3000000

    @pytest.mark.skip(reason="Not for TestEverything")
    def test_sub_negative_numbers(self):
        assert my_sub(-1, -2) == 1

    @pytest.mark.skip(reason="Not for TestEverything")
    def test_mul_zero(self):
        x = random.randint(1,400)
        assert my_mul(0, x) == 0
```

test_all_functions.py

```
import pytest, file2
from file2 import TestCollection

class TestEverything:
    def test_dummy_local(self):
        assert True == True
    """ Adding stuff like this here is totally useless, 
        what is imported from the first file, it is 
        tested, except if the skip is specified..  

    def test_addnum(self):
        if hasattr(TestAddNumbers, "test_add_numbers"):
            test = TestAddNumbers()
            test.test_add_numbers(1,2,3)

    def test_addlargenum(self):
        if hasattr(TestAddNumbers, "test_add_large_numbers"):
            test = TestAddNumbers()
            test.test_add_large_numbers()
    """
```

Output:

```
Desktop/test_all_functions.py::TestAddNumbers::test_add_numbers[1-2-3] PASSED                                                  [ 12%]
Desktop/test_all_functions.py::TestAddNumbers::test_add_numbers[0-0-0] PASSED                                                  [ 25%]
Desktop/test_all_functions.py::TestAddNumbers::test_add_numbers[-1-1-0] PASSED                                                 [ 37%]
Desktop/test_all_functions.py::TestAddNumbers::test_add_numbers[2--4--2] PASSED                                                [ 50%]
Desktop/test_all_functions.py::TestAddNumbers::test_add_large_numbers PASSED                                                   [ 62%]
Desktop/test_all_functions.py::TestAddNumbers::test_sub_negative_numbers SKIPPED (Not needed for TestEverything)               [ 75%]
Desktop/test_all_functions.py::TestAddNumbers::test_mul_zero SKIPPED (Not needed for TestEverything)                           [ 87%]
Desktop/test_all_functions.py::TestEverything::test_dummy_local PASSED                               [100%]

============================================= 6 passed, 2 skipped in 0.03s ==============================================
```